# How to detect and mark all textareas in a website

Tags: jquery

i want to know the way to find and mark all text(areas) in a website.

I need, it to add a kind of text-editor.

For example

```
my first text, outside all
<p>my p text</p>
<div>my div<span>my span inner div</span></div>
<div><img....>Text</div>
...
```

This content i should change in a way like this

```
<editor id=1>my first text, outside all</editor>
<p>
<editor id=2>my p text</editor></p>
<div>
<editor id=3>my div<span>my span inner div</span></editor></div>
<div><img....>
<editor id=4>Text</editor></div>
...
```

Thanks for your idears and help.

Comment: For starters, `<editor id=1>my first text, outside all</editor>` isn't valid markup. Your question makes pretty much zero sense not to mention the total lack of effort from yourself.

Comment: If I understand your question right, you want to wrap all texts in input fields ?

Comment: That still make no sense, input fields don't contain text. I'd suggest the OP needs to have at least some basic HTML knowledge here.

Comment: @ari yes nearly, that my intention, more contenteditable

Comment: @Liam, you'r right, the <editor tags are a kind of placeholder, if your are happier i can change to <code or <p or what else :-)

Comment: Not possible.  Especially how you expect the <span> tag inside the 3rd editor tag to be maintained.  You can't selectively wildcard something.  However you could do a for each on all P and DIV tags.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/gqKGgm

As I said, what you want isn't entirely possible but this might help you figure something out.

```
my first text, outside all
<p>my p text</p>
<div>my div<span>my span inner div</span></div>
<div><img....>Text</div>
```

```
$('p').each(function() {
  $(this).html('...tag-here...<editor>'+$(this).html()+'</editor>...tag-here...');
});

$('div').each(function() {
  $(this).html('...tag-here...<editor>'+$(this).html()+'</editor>...tag-here...');
});
```

Comment: Just as an FYI, I added "...tag-here..." so it would display in CodePen.  Also, keep in mind that using "each" like this in jQuery can be sort of "expensive" in the sense that it is about 10x slower than a native JavaScript loop.  Something to keep in mind if you plan to use this for a ton of items in a single page.